# I am having 2 same .txt files where in naming, 1 part is same and other part is different. I want to print the files based on the condition below

Tags: shell, unix, teradata, ksh, unix-timestamp

- file name 1 : `alert_human_*.txt`
- file name 2 : `alert_human_abc_*.txt`

`*` denotes the timestamp

I am trying to write these filenames to `availablefiles.txt` file which is placed in `human/temp` directory by searching the files using a shell script that I have kept in different directory (`human/stg`).

**Note** I have kept only `alert_human_*.txt` in `human/stg` directory.  But it writes that file as `alert_human_abc_*.txt`.

So based on below condition I want to print the filenames.

1. `alert_human_abc_*.txt` - if this file is present, it should print only this filename.
2. `alert_human_*.txt` - if this file is present, it should print only this filename which should not print as 1st mentioned file name.

I have used like

```
echo 'alert_human_abc_*.txt > temp/availablefiles.txt
echo 'alert_human_*.txt > temp/availablefiles.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not super clear, but here goes.

```
#!/bin/bash

outputfile='human/temp/availablefiles.txt'

abc_filename="alert_human_abc_*.txt"
noabc_filename="alert_human_*.txt"
if [[ $(find . -name "$abc_filename") ]]
then
    echo "$abc_filename" >"$outputfile"
else
    echo "$noabc_filename" >"$outputfile"
fi
```

- If any file matches `alert_human_abc_*.txt`, that matching pattern is written to the file.
- Otherwise, the pattern `alert_human_*.txt` is written.

---

If you wanted the list of files that match each pattern in your output file, modify like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

outputfile='human/temp/availablefiles.txt'

abc_filename="alert_human_abc_*.txt"
noabc_filename="alert_human_*.txt"
if [[ $(find . -name "$abc_filename") ]]
then
    find . -name "$abc_filename" >"$outputfile"
else
    find . -name "$noabc_filename" >"$outputfile"
fi
```

- Instead of writing the pattern, write the result of `find` using that pattern to the output file.